# Firefox extension to always open a link in the same tab

Tags: gratis, firefox, web, hyperlink

Please recommend a Firefox Web Extension that allows the user to always open a link in the same tab.

I'm open to any way for it to be enabled.  The functionality can be "always on", meaning it affects all links, or can be enabled "per link" via a context menu or keyboard shortcut.

Should be gratis.  Prefer intentionally open-source, but it's not a requirement, since every Firefox Web Extension is essentially open-source.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for your idea, Moishe.  When I Ctrl+click on a link that normally opens in a new tab, it opens in a new background tab, not the same tab.

Comment: Are we looking for the same thing here? [Firefox Quantum extension that will keep links from opening new tabs by removing the remove target attributes "_blank" and "_new" from links](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/49803/623)

Comment: @galacticninja Good question. I'm tempted to mark my question as a duplicate of yours, but your question is much more specific than mine in that it defines how the extension must work.  Your question also requires the answerer to have more technical knowledge and understanding in order to comprehend the question.  I think we can leave them both, as they each may attract answers by people with different knowledge levels, but keep your comment that references your question.  Alternatively, we could combine the 2 questions into 1.  I'm good either way.